# Can you laterally invert a virtual image?

Tags: optics, reflection

Could you possibly make a mirror that would show how you look to a person in front of you instead of laterally inverting the image?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-reversing_mirror

Comment: Yes, it's called a non-reversing mirror. [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-reversing_mirror)

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about this, but that's really interesting.

Comment: Please consider writing a standalone answer so that this question will be useful to future readers without the need to follow another link.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you can do this with a V-shaped mirror:

[image]

Wikipedia has an article about it: [Non-reversing mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-reversing_mirror).